# Is flux.jl supported by Paperspace gradient?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia, flux.jl

Hi I am trying to use [flux.jl](https://fluxml.ai/Flux.jl/stable/) in a Paperspace gradient notebook.
Is this supported and if so what's the easiest way to start? is there a demo notebook?

I [found this repo](https://github.com/JuliaIPU/JuliaIpuDemo) for Julia IPUs on Paperspace which has a "run on gradient" button, so I was wondering if there is a similar demo notebook for julia + flux.jl